# Java - errors on visual programs in Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Stacktrace error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059167/java-stacktrace-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0)

I am using eclipse, and every time I try to run a program in Linux that uses visuals, I get the following errors and it doesn't display anything in the applet. In Windows, everything runs just fine. I have tried re-installing the JDK and the JRE, but to no avail. Furthermore, I have tried the advice from the following links:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=83466
- [Unable to run java gui programs with ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu)

I am running Bodhi Linux, which is based on Ubuntu.

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: GraphicsSkeletton : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:314)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(AppletClassLoader.java:146)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(AppletClassLoader.java:608)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:798)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:727)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:380)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Example you have compiled your source codes in java 1.5 and you are trying to run them in java 1.6

Check your java version

```
java -version
```

will give you java version you are using

Comment: I think I may be having trouble updating java then, because I still can't get it working.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the JRE wasn't were I thought it was. It was in the JDK folder rather than it's own folder where I remember putting it. Oh well, it's all working now!

Answer (score 1):

It means you have compiled in higher version of JDK and running on different (incompatible, lower) version of JRE.