# Viewpager in Xml Layout Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to add a viewpager inside a fragment but when I wrote following:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This produced following exception while rendering:

"`Exception raised during rendering: android/support/v4/view/ViewPager : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`"

Can anyone tell why this is happening and what should I do to solve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11059167/java-stacktrace-error-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0

Comment: Which log you are talking about?

Comment: update your java http://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/1638739

Answer (score 0):

download JDK 7, and change the default JDK from 1.6 to 1.7

3.1 Download and install openjdk-7-jdk

$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre

3.2 Change the default Java to 1.7 (Working on Debian like system only).

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection

```
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode

  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode

  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
```

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 
to provide /usr/bin/java
```

(java) in manual mode

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

for more info see below link:-

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

Go to Project > Properties > Java Compiler.

Enable Project specific settings, and change Compiler Compliance Level to 1.6 or lower.

Test your app again.